# Make oversized image cover page number

Tags: graphics, page-numbering

Sometimes I have images that extend below the bottom margin since I want to use the entire `textwidth` while preserving the image ratio. When this happens, is it possible to make the image cover the page number? Currently the page number appears above the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=23cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` to remove printing of the page number.
2. Use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) (or something similar) to insert the over-sized image in the `F`ore`G`round and therefore overwrite the page number; here's an example:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}

   \begin{document}

   \mbox{}% Add something on the page
   \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
     \AtTextUpperLeft{%
       \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=23cm]{example-image-a}}%
     }%
   }%

   \clearpage % Move to next page

   The rest of your document goes here \ldots

   \end{document}
   ```

Regardless of the choice, using a `figure` placed `H`ere will overflow to the following page if it doesn't fit on the current one, unless you adjust the height to fit within the text block.

Comment: For the first solution I had to add  `\pagebreak  \thispagestyle{empty}  \begin{figure} (overflowing figure)....` for it to work in the right page.